# Is Euclidean distance the same as distance-from-correlation as $d(x, y) = \sqrt{2m[1 - r(x, y)]}$

Tags: correlation, distance, euclidean

I found in a couple of documents (e.g. [this](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/clustering-distance-measures/)) that the Euclidean distance $d(x, y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(x_i - y_i)^2}}$ can be obtained from correlation coeffcient if $x$ and $y$ are standardised vectors (i.e. their mean is 0 and standard deviation is 1) using the formula:

$$
d(x, y) = \sqrt{2m[1 - r(x, y)]}
$$

where $m$ is the dimension of vectors $x$ and $y$ and $r$ the correlation coefficient.

I tried to empirically verify that the equations are indeed the same but I get slightly different results. Here's some examples using the iris dataset in R:

```
18.24927 # Distance using "direct" Euclidean distance for Sepal.Length vs Sepal.Width
18.31041 # Distance derived from correlation coefficient

6.18202  # Same as above for Sepal.Length vs Petal.Length
6.202731

3.326575 # Same as above for Petal.Width vs Petal.Length
3.337719
```

The two methods give similar results but not quite the same. Is it due to some internal rounding error or am I missing something?

---

Here's the R code:

````
eucl_dist_from_r <- function(m) {
    r <- cor(m[,1], m[,2])
    d <- sqrt(2 * nrow(m) * (1 - r))
    return(d)
}

m <- scale(cbind(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width))
dist(t(m), method = "euclidean")
eucl_dist_from_r(m)

m <- scale(cbind(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length))
dist(t(m), method = "euclidean")
eucl_dist_from_r(m)

m <- scale(cbind(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Petal.Length))
dist(t(m), method = "euclidean")
eucl_dist_from_r(m)
```
````

Comment: I found this link https://cmci.colorado.edu/classes/INFO-1301/files/borgatti.htm that discusses the connection between the euclidean distance and correlation, that might help you.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 - thanks. I skimmed through your link and it seems to confirm the connection between Euclidean distance and $r$. Yet, something in my implementation makes the two methods return slightly different results. Why is that?

Comment: This connection holds for standardized data, so try to check if the SCALE() function does that, or it normalize your data also.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 yes - `scale()` returns standardised data within machine precision error like `colMeans(m) -> -4.480675e-16  2.035409e-16`. I don't know if this tiny imprecision escalates to the bigger one I observe. I guess that's part of the question I'm asking.

Comment: I just run your code and it works fine, the results are almost identical. I wouldn't worry about the fact that the results are not exact.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 I'm not worried about the practical difference. I'm just interested in where the discrepancy comes from. A difference of ~1% is usually much bigger than the error from the machine internal rounding.

Comment: What I would do in order to check where the discrepancy comes from, I would demonstrate a simple example where I can actually calculate things by hand. Then I'd check which R, functions give results that deviate from my calculations, and then I would go and check how these functions are programmed.

Comment: Please read the manual page for `scale`, which shows that it is *not* the correct function for standardizing in this context.  You can adjust it by multiplying `m` by `sqrt(n/(n-1))` where `n <- nrow(iris)`.  "Internal rounding" could affect the results only by up to one part in $10^{-15}$ or so.

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot! I posted an answer based on your comment. Hope I got it right!

Answer (score 1):

(Following @whuber's comment)

In this case, we want to standardize the input data using the population standard deviation $sd = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}{(x_{i} - \mu)^2}}$ instead of the sample standard deviation $sd = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}{(x_{i} - \mu)^2}}$. This latter being the one used by R's `scale` (and `sd`) function.

Now things add up:

```
eucl_dist_from_r <- function(m) {
    r <- cor(m[,1], m[,2])
    d <- sqrt(2 * nrow(m) * (1 - r))
    return(d)
}

pop_sd <- function(x) {
    mu <- mean(x)
    ss <- sum((x - mu)^2)
    stdev <- sqrt(ss / length(x)) 
    return(stdev)
}

standardize <- function(x) {
    return((x - mean(x)) / pop_sd(x))
}

m <- cbind(standardize(iris$Sepal.Length), standardize(iris$Petal.Length))

dist(t(m))
6.202731

eucl_dist_from_r(m)
6.202731
```

(Follow up question would be: Why in *this* case we want the population stdev?)

Comment: Answer to your last question: because that's what is needed to obtain the Euclidean distance.